# How can I change the styling of a NAV based on what page React-Router has selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using React Router to construct my NAV header bar.

Based on what page my application is routed to, I would like to alter the styling of the header.

For example, in the code below if my application is routed to "/" I would like for the NAV to have styling defined as:

```
className={classes.HeaderA}
src={headerLogoA}
className={classes.LogoA}
```

But if it is routed to "/video" or "/industry" I would like for the NAV to have styling defined as:

```
className={classes.HeaderB}
src={headerLogoB}
className={classes.LogoB}
```

I thought about using the state variable "originalHeader" to determine what type of styling is used, "true" for styling A or "false" for styling B.

I thought I could have either the specific "Route" or "NavLink" tag change this variable to either "true" or "false" using "this.setState({ originalHeader: false})". Such as:

```
<NavLink {this.setState({ originalHeader: false})} to="/video" exact>About<br></br>OpenSeatDirect</NavLink>
```

Or,

```
<Route {this.setState({ originalHeader: false})} path="/video" exact component={ Video }/>
```

I would then define a variable such as "NavType" to return the "Nav" section of my code with either styling A or B based on the value of "originalHeader". Even though the code below shows this variable defined, I did not use it later in the code.

When I tried to add "this.setState({ originalHeader: false})" to either the starting "Route" or "NavLink" tag an error was thrown.

Any suggestions?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import Aux from '../../hoc/Auxiliary/Auxiliary';
import Main from '../../containers/Main/Main';
import Video from '../../containers/Video/Video';
import Industry from '../../containers/Industry/Industry';

import classes from './Layout.css';
import headerLogoA from '../../imageA.png';
import headerLogoB from '../../imageB.png';

class Layout extends Component {
    state = {
        originalHeader: true
    }

    let NavType = (
        if (this.state.originalHeader) {
            return (
                <Nav className={classes.HeaderA}>
                    <ul >
                        <li><img src={headerLogoA} className={classes.LogoA}/></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/" exact>Home<br></br>Page</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/video" exact>About<br></br>OpenSeatDirect</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/industry" exact>Industry<br></br>Overview</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                </Nav>
        else {
            return (
                <Nav className={classes.HeaderB}>
                    <ul >
                        <li><img src={headerLogoB} className={classes.LogoB}/></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/" exact>Home<br></br>Page</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/video" exact>About<br></br>OpenSeatDirect</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/industry" exact>Industry<br></br>Overview</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                </Nav>

    render () {
        return (
            <Aux>     


                // I though of replacing this section with "{NavType}"      
                <Nav className={classes.HeaderA}>
                    <ul >
                        <li><img src={headerLogoA} className={classes.LogoA}/></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/" exact>Home<br></br>Page</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/video" exact>About<br></br>OpenSeatDirect</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/industry" exact>Industry<br></br>Overview</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                </Nav>
                // up to here would be replace with "{NavType}"


                <Route path="/" exact component={ Main }/>
                <Route path="/video" exact component={ Video }/>
                <Route path="/industry" exact component={ Industry }/>

            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options depending on how you want to do things. In my personal opinion however the header is not part of the pages so should be rendered separately. Hence I would render the page with the correct header at the route level. You can do this by changing the render method if the route from "component" to "render" and include a header component before the page.

```
<Route
    path="/video"
    exact
    render={(routeProps) => 
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header styleType={1}/>
            <Video />
        </React.Fragment> }/> 
    }
/>
```

Another option would be to test the router properties inside the page component and styling the header accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set state on click of a Link, you could try a click handler on the Link:

```
onClick={()=>{this.setState({originalHeader:false})}}
```

If the nav is rendered by the route component, you could read the url in componentDidMount() and componentWillReceiveProps(). For that use

```
this.props.location.path
```

and change the state based on the value.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, it did clarify how I can make changes to "state" via a click handler.